# How can an arduino nano hold such a large array?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, arduino, out-of-memory

For a project with the arduino nano, I need an array of integers as large as possible. I looked at the specs for the nano, and it has 2KB of SRAM. Given that every int is 4 bytes, you'd think that the arduino can hold 2048 / 4 = 512 ints. However, when compiling(not uploading) the following code, I get no "Out of memory" errors.

```
int mem[16383];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

However, the following code *does* produce an error.

```
int mem[16384];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

The error is: "Size of array 'mem' too large".

How can this be? Will something break or will memory be corrupted if I use this huge array?

Thanks!

Comment: `int` is 2 bytes on arduino

Comment: http://arduino.land/FAQ/content/6/7/en/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-elements-an-array-can-have.html

Comment: So, how does the compiler know the amount of memory for your arduino?  You could have an arduino with more memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, you usually set the Arduino model before compile. It may be even autoconfigured when you connect the Arduino to the dev pc.

Comment: @StefanoBuora my model is set to nano

Comment: The link posted by @wxz is the answer you are looking for. A question: can you write in your array - even of 16383 elements in size? (I expect not)